# compression problems excell using Maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

the problem very easy the form that i try to compress a file is the next

```
 $zipname = 'file.zip';
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
 $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
 $zip->addFile(Excel::download(new SheetsExports($page1, $page2), $filename . '.xls'));
  $zip->close()
 echo 'Archive created!'
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=files.zip');
 header('Content-type: application/zip');
 <!-- end snippet -->
 $zip->close()
 echo 'Archive created!';
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=files.zip');
 header('Content-type: application/zip');
```

in a laravel controller , i use the external library Maatwebsite
then when i execute the brwoser apair the next error

---

**Corrupted Content Error**

---

The site at http://hall.test/indiceDeRotacion?_token=2Eh6WAl0W43l8ANzLz0e4GGW9reV04ESpURvEi1H&almacen=PRINCIPAL&fechaDesde=2018-05-01&fechaHasta=2019-04-30&proveedor=3000 familia=&type=xls&compresion=on&email=&asunto=&submit=informe

---

so i need a solution , or another external library or the correct way in my code for it works

Comment: What do you mean by "compress"? What happens with the given code?

Comment: it´s a ZIP file

Comment: So, if the result of that code is a ZIP file, what's the problem?

Comment: Well, I have a problem trying to get an excell compressed file using the maatwebsite plugin in a laravel proyect

Comment: That might be the reason for you posting it here - but what **exactly** is this problem? Is there any error message given? What happens when you run the code? And how is this different to what you expect this code to do?

Comment: Corrupted Content Error

The site at http://hall.test/indiceDeRotacion?_token=LwMFB6w0PcupEoVDya00zOMDAEjqEZ3rEY0QFHSP&almacen=PRINCIPAL&fechaDesde=2018-05-14&fechaHasta=2019-05-13&proveedor=3000&familia=&type=xls&compresion=on&email=&asunto=&submit=informe has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired.

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.

    Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem

Comment: Have you checked the server's error log for more details? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: ok i re-edit the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix the issue with this code

```
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open('yyyy.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
            $zip->addFile(Excel::download(new SheetsExports($page1, $page2),  $filename . '.xls')->getFile(),
                'xxxx.xls');
            $zip->close();
        }
        return response()->download("yyyy.zip");
```